# why it insert extra two null row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert multiple row, when I'm insert data it take extra two null row. but why it is happening...Please some one help me to solve this problem.........
this is my form page

```
<?php
require_once 'Insert_class.php';
$obj_Insert_class=new Insert_class();
$new= $obj_Insert_class->employee_select_data();
$massage='';
if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
    $massage=$obj_Insert_class->time_add();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <h2>Multiple Insert</h2>
        <?php  echo $massage;   ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table width='30%'>
                <tr>
                    <td><u><b>EMPLOYEE NAME</b></u></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($new)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input name="eid[]" class="case" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['eid']; ?>" /></td>
                        <td><input name="employee_name[]" class="case" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['employee_name'] ?>"/></td>
                        <td><input name="status[]" class="case" type="text" value="1"/></td>
                        <td><input name="first[]" id="first" type="number"/></td>
                        <td><input name="second[]" id="second" type="number"/></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="btn" value="Submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>     
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my insert class page

```
<?php

require './connect.php';

class Insert_class extends Connect {

    protected $link;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->link = $this->conntection();
    }

    public function time_add() {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_POST as $val) {
            error_reporting(0);
            $eid = $_POST['eid'][$i];
            $name = $_POST['employee_name'][$i];
            $status = $_POST['status'][$i];
            $first = $_POST['first'][$i];
            $second = $_POST['second'][$i];
            $new_add = $first + $second;
            $SQL = "INSERT INTO time(eid,name,status,first,seconc,new_add)VALUES('$eid','$name','$status','$first','$second','$new_add')";
            if (mysqli_query($this->link, $SQL)) {
                $massage = 'DATA Susseccfully inserted';
            } else {
                die('Select query problem' . mysqli_error($this->link));
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return $massage;

    }

    public function employee_select_data() {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM employee";

        if (mysqli_query($this->link, $SQL)) {
            $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $SQL);
            return $result;
        } else {
            die('Select query problem' . mysqli_error($this->link));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: For every value you submit, you run an `insert`: `foreach ($_POST as $val) { INSERT }`. Change your code to do `insert` only once (and **not** for every value)

Comment: yea but at the end it take extra two null row

Comment: The concept of your code is wrong.

Comment: Looping over `$_POST` doesn't do what you think it does.  You need to explode one of your `$_POST` array values into an array and loop over *that*.

Comment: so how can i solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains this loop.

```
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($_POST as $val) {  /* wrong! */
        /* do the insert */
        $i ++;
   }
```

This makes no sense. The `$_POST` is an array of values posted from your form. This loop iterates over each value in that array. That's too many iterations.

Instead, you need to figure out the size of the arrays in your form-field elements of `$_POST`.  Try something like this:

```
$some_field = $_POST['eid'];
$i = 0;
foreach ($some_field as $junk) {
    /* do the insert */
    $i++;
}
```